# Change image source with Javascript - basic function not working

Tags: javascript, image, addeventlistener, src

New to JavaScript so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a carousel of 2 images, changing on click. I've tried to figure it out but no luck. Thanks.

```js
function changeImg() {
  if (document.getElementById("carousel-image").src == "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=img1") {
    document.getElementById("carousel-image").src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=img2";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("carousel-image").src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=img1";
  }
}

document.getElementById("carousel-image").addEventListener("click", changeImg);
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=img1" id="carousel-image" alt="space nebula" class="topimages">

<script src="my-script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems to work as designed after I created a snippet and added an image that exists

Comment: works for me - just check your image paths

Comment: Simpler: `function changeImg() {
  var src = document.getElementById("carousel-image").src;
  document.getElementById("carousel-image").src = src.indexOf("img1") !== -1 ? "img2.jpg" : "img1.jpg";
}`

Comment: Press F12 and network to see if your images are loaded

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but here is a more robust ES6 version of it that should work for cases with more than just the two images.

```
function changeCarouselImage(event) {
    const carouselImages= [
        "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=img1",
        "https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=img2",
    ];

    const currentImage = event.target.src;
    const currentImageIndex = carouselImages.findIndex(img => img === currentImage);

    const nextImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1;
    if (nextImageIndex >= carouselImages.length){
        nextImageIndex = 0;
    }

    event.target.src = carouselImages[nextImageIndex];
}

document.getElementById("carousel-image").addEventListener("click", changeCarouselImage);
```